# Can't enable automatic login for the administrator account on server

Tags: 16.04, gnome, auto-login

I can't enable automatic login for the administrator account on my server, running 16.04 LTS.

[image]

The button is greyed out and nothing happens when I click on it.

Before you go all crazy, it's my hobby server at home, and if this is a massive security issue doesn't really matter.

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show only part of the User Accounts dialog - the full dialog should include an 'Unlock' button at the top right

Comment: @steeldriver That's it! Thank you! If you don't mind posting this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

As @steeldriver said in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887997/cant-enable-automatic-login-for-the-administrator-account-on-server#comment1387499_887997), click on the `unlock` button top right, and after that you should be able to change the switch.

[image: unlock]